# Are Ultegra 10 Speed Sprockets available separately?

Tags: cassette

I'm looking to buy some Ultegra 10 speed sprockets, specifically a 16,18,23 and 25. Are these available separately?

Comment: Unlikely - most cassettes these days are one-piece. excluding the small locking ring and small cog.   Feel free to google and prove me wrong !

Comment: While cassettes often can be disassembled, and the cogs interchanged, the combos that will or won't work are unpredictable, and there's good reason for the cogs to not be sold individually.

Comment: I think >=10 speed are actually rivetted on Shimano, not using tiny screws. So, it'd be a PITA to disassemble+reassemble if you wanted to do that by cannibalizing a bunch of cassettes to get the appropriate cogs. And you might not get decent shifting due to ramp design.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Shimano makes some replacement 11/12/13t cogs available for Dura Ace, Ultegra, XTR, and XT, and that's it.